Odata feed from sharepoint server to get MS Project data
I am trying to fetch MsProject Server data from sharepoint 2019 into PowerBI Desktop via following API
/_api/ProjectData/
Its showing the data in preview but not loading into Power BI. Any suggestion what I am doing wrong !
